# How to compare NSDate objects efficiently

Tags: performance, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I have to compare many managed objects and group them by date. I can't use NSDateComponents because it's too slow to compare two `NSDate` objects.

How can I compare them in a more efficient way, so that I can save processing time?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what kind of comparison you are doing but you can do:

```
if ( [date1 timeIntervalSince1970] > [date2 timeIntervalSince1970])
{
    NSLOG(@"Do something");
}
```

so if date1 is bigger (further away for 1970!) than date2 the if is true.
This will work quicker than NSDateComponents.